# Django error while saving Foreign Key - Can not assign none , Doesn't allow null values

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have two models - Events and Tenants.

```
class EventsModel(models.Model):
    sys_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False, blank=True)
    tenant_sys_id = models.ForeignKey('tenant.TenantModel', on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=False, blank=False)
    start_date_time = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False)
    end_date_time = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False) 
    created_when = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=True)   

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.created_when = timezone.now()
        self.tenant_sys_id = 1 #for-testing-only. actual current_logged_in_user.tenant_sys_id
        return super(EventsModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This model have a FK tenant_sys_id to tenant model. If for this I set null = False then below error is thrown.

```
ValueError('Cannot assign None: "EventsModel.tenant_sys_id" does not allow null values.',)
```

I am setting the value of this field in overridden save method from the logged in user details.
Setting null = True doesn't throw this error.

However is I do the same for created_when field this behavior is not shown. Irrespective of null=True/False, value is being set from save method and saved.

I am getting this error in View File.

```
form = EventsForm(request.POST)
print(request.POST) # print
print(form) # do not print. error here <--
if form.is_valid(): # error here if above line is commented.
    form.save()
```

ModelForm class

```
class EventsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EventsModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

So here I am not able to understand -

1. why I must set FK to null=True and not created_when in order to work.
2. Why it is throwing error while creating form and not while saving data.

Answer (score 0):

Your ForeignKey should be called `tenant_sys`, not `tenant_sys_id`. Django will automatically add the `_id` suffix to the underlying database field, but the value you have in Python is actually an instance of the target model, not an ID.

With the code you have, you are still not setting the db value; you set the object, which Django will actually convert into `tenant_sys_id_id`, but the db column remains empty, hence the integrity error. The reason why there is no form validation error is because you also have `blank=True` on the field definition.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I still have questions -  (1) I am getting the error while creating form object from ModelForm class and not in save method. (2) Why it works when I set null = True on FK.

Comment: Also this - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24787 . According to this there is no way we can use null= False and blank=True on a FK in models.